# Why is Postgres choosing a Hash-Join instead of a Nested Join that is 200x faster?

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan, subquery, query-performance

I run the following query against Postgres 9.5 which returns article information along with the currently valid price:

```
WITH selected_article_rm(id) AS (
  VALUES
    ('80512e52-a406-4a9b-a8df-b9d8807e736d' :: UUID),
    ('2d459a9f-b42c-4c03-b24f-2de602addc69' :: UUID),
    -- 50 entries selected
)
SELECT *
FROM selected_article_rm
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (article_price_rm.article_id)
               article_price_rm.ppub_price AS price,
               article_price_rm.article_id AS article_id
             FROM article_price_rm
             WHERE article_price_rm.valid_from <= now()
             ORDER BY article_price_rm.article_id, article_price_rm.valid_from DESC) AS current_article_price ON current_article_price.article_id = selected_article_rm.id;
```

Sidenote: the CTE is merely used to debug this performance issue, the productive query uses a `WHERE article_price_rm.id IN (?, ?, ...)` but behaves exactly the same

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns the following execution plan:

```
Merge Right Join  (cost=3.46..10339.48 rows=50 width=38) (actual time=0.295..70.697 rows=50 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (article_price_rm.article_id = selected_article_rm.id)
  CTE selected_article_rm
    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.62 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=0.42..8547.81 rows=143031 width=30) (actual time=0.026..60.548 rows=156218 loops=1)
        ->  Index Only Scan using i on article_price_rm  (cost=0.42..8065.89 rows=192766 width=30) (actual time=0.025..36.707 rows=186266 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (valid_from <= now())
              Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Sort  (cost=2.41..2.54 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=0.040..0.058 rows=50 loops=1)
        Sort Key: selected_article_rm.id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  CTE Scan on selected_article_rm  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.017 rows=50 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.144 ms
Execution time: 70.727 ms
```

As you can see, Postgres chooses to first filter out the currently valid prices for all 190'000 articles, then performs a hash-join with the 50 selected articles.

Bottom-Line:

## Why is Postgres not choosing a nested loop in this scenario?

### What I've tried so far

Recomputing the statistics for `article_price_rm` did not help, neither did a `VACUUM ANALYZE`.

The difference in cardinalities (190'000 vs. 50) is overwhelming, so I doubt that altering the planner cost constant for `random_page_cost` would do much good (we use the defaults).

I can force Postgres into performing a nested-loop join as follows:

```
WITH selected_article_rm(id) AS (
  VALUES
    ('80512e52-a406-4a9b-a8df-b9d8807e736d' :: UUID),
    ('2d459a9f-b42c-4c03-b24f-2de602addc69' :: UUID),
    -- 50 entries selected
)
SELECT *
FROM selected_articles_rm
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT article_price_rm.ppub_price AS price
                      FROM article_price_rm
                      WHERE article_price_rm.article_id = selected_articles_rm.id AND valid_from <= now()
                      ORDER BY article_price_rm.article_id, valid_from DESC
                      LIMIT 1) AS article_price;
```

but this has the disadvantage that it is only faster than a hash-join if few articles are selected. However, it demonstrates that a nested-loop join would be vastly cheaper:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=1.05..224.75 rows=50 width=22) (actual time=0.025..0.361 rows=50 loops=1)
  CTE selected_articles_rm
    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.62 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.028 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  CTE Scan on selected_articles_rm  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=50 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.041 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=50)
        ->  Index Only Scan using i on article_price_rm  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=30) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=50)
              Index Cond: ((article_id = selected_articles_rm.id) AND (valid_from <= now()))
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.225 ms
Execution time: 0.401 ms
```